# How can I send an input type email between 2 files php?

Tags: php, mysql, email, web

I have used this method in one php:

```
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$user1 = $user['Email'];
header (Location: modify_email.php?user1=$user1);
```

And in the other .php:

```
Email:
<input name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['user1'];?>" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
```

But I only obtain the first part, to @, no more.

Example: If I have user1@user.com I received user1

How can I solve it without put the input type to text?

I have see the problem, it is that when I insert an email in the database, it only saves the first part to @, why could be the problem?

I use a form with input type email to send it too

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a lot of things wrong with your code.

1) dont use mysql, and use mysqli or PDO instead

2) Use session_start() and $_SESSION;

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['email'] = $user['Email'];
header('Location: w/e');
```

then do

```
session_start()
<input name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain good. The second page is html so that I can't put session_start because it says me that a session had already started.. How can I solve it?

Comment: session already started, meaning dont include session_start() in 2nd file.

Comment: I have see the problem, it is that when I insert an email in the database, it only saves the first part to @, why could be the problem?

I use a form with input type email to send it too

Comment: post the code that you use to insert things into database.

Comment: I have see the fault, I pass the $name instead of $email... what a stupid! Sorry and many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose header to double quotes.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
     }
```

will prevent PHP from saying that session has alredy started.

Then use `$_SESSION` like Dimi stated in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
header (Location: modify_email.php?user1=$user1);
```

to:

```
header('Location: modify_email.php?user1='.urlencode($user1));
```

Also to avoid being hacked through XSS use htmlspecialchars like this:

```
<input name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['user1']);?>" required="" autofocus="" type="email">
```